# Are there any genetically modified GMO squash with a vine growth habit which grow back from the root?

Tags: genetics, botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

When I cut Scottish thistles with scissors, the thistle grows back from the tap root.

When I accidentally step on squash vines, the squash vine dies.

I was wondering if genetics research has produced more robust foliage which withstands being stepped on. It seems like some cultivars of squash have healthier stronger stems and leaves, than other cultivars.

Comment: Hi and welcome. We ask for evidence of an attempt to answer this yourself when posting. Have you searched the internet for any such genetic modifications of squash? Do you understand the physical make-up of a thistle taproot and why it's able to regenerate top growth when severed off at the base? Neither the taproot nor the squash vine are foliage. Foliage is dispensable to a degree; plant vasculature is not.